# Jquery nor javascript running on this page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I need a jquery to function to run on page load. I could not get it to work so I took the page and jquery script down to bare bones yet it still does not work. Here is the page:

```
<head>
    <title>Jump Page</title>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">


          $(function () {
              alert("test");

          });

    </script>
        <div>Report data is being loaded...</div>
        <img id="spinner" src="Styles/spinner.gif" />
</body>


</html>
```

No alert is shown. I've been able to accomplish this in MVC - why is this extremely simple page giving me so much grief?

Note: No script errors are given in IE and the source looks identical to what is shown here.

Comment: That should work, did you forget to copy the jQuery file to the scripts directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't shorthand `<script>` tags, you need to put in the closing `</script>` tag

Answer (score 4):

The script tag cannot be an empty tag. Change to this and it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


      $(function () {
          alert("test");

      });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Close the script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" /></script>
```